# gnupg encrypt file failed ENCRYPTION_COMPLIANCE_MODE

Tags: python, gnupg

I'm using Python 3.7.6, gnupg 2.3.1, i tried to encrypt a file but failed, here is my code:

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
key_data=open("/path-to-public-key", "rb").read()
import_result=gpg.import_keys(key_data)
pprint(import_result.results)

with open("/my_data_00000.dat", "rb") as f:
  gpg.encrypt(f, <finger print from import_result.results>, output="/my_data_00000.dat.gpg")
```

it failed: ValueError: Unknown status message: 'ENCRYPTION_COMPLIANCE_MODE'

one thing i'm confused is the key, if i ran this code:

```
gpg = gnupg.GPG()
key_data=open("/path-to-public-key", "rb").read()
import_result=gpg.import_keys(key_data)
pprint(import_result.results)
```

it showed result as:

```
[{'fingerprint': 'finger-print-1',
  'status': 'Not actually changed\n'},
 {'status': 'key considered'}]
```

if i ran this code:

```
pubkeys = gpg.list_keys()
print("pubkeys: ")
pprint(pubkeys)
```

it showed result as:

```
pubkeys: 
[{'algo': '1',
  'date': '1523494796',
  'dummy': '',
  'expires': '',
  'fingerprint': 'finger-print-2',
  'keyid': '38MOQQBD63C93BE4',
  'length': '2048',
  'ownertrust': '-',
  'rev': {},
  'sigs': {'filetrans <test@test.com>': []},
  'subkeys': [['xxx', 'e'], ['xxxxx', 'es']],
  'trust': '-',
  'type': 'pub',
  'uids': ['filetrans <test@test.com>']}]
```

I noticed the finger-print-1 and finger-print-2 are different, which one should I use to encrypt the file?

if i directly ran from command line with the same public key it encrypted successfully:

```
gpg --output /my_data_00000.dat.gpg --encrypt --recipient <test@test.com> /my_data_00000.dat
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `python-gnupg` instead? I was running into the same issue. I deleted `gnupg` and installed `python-gnupg`. That seemed to do the trick for me.